# Close socket connection in request.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcplistener

I have a program that uses 'request' module to fetch html.

Is there a way to manually close socket connection after receiving a response other than abort as well as remove all listeners from that particular request instance.

The main problem is that, as the program continues making requests, the number of file descriptors and listeners, keeps growing, regardless of using abort() after the fetch is done.

Finally, the program ends after it reaches a maxListeners size, which is already set for 20000.

```js
const request=require('request')
fetchUrl (params, tag, callBack) {
    this.url = params.url
    this.tag = tag
    let headers = { 'User-Agent': params.useragent }
    let options = { followRedirects: false, keepAlive: false, url: params.url, headers: headers, gzip: true, encoding: null }
    let proxy = 'None'
    let userAgent = params.useragent
    
    if (parseInt(ConfigHandler.getConfig().spfUseProxy) === 1) {
      if (parseInt(ConfigHandler.getConfig().spfUseHermesUserAgent) === 1) {
        userAgent = params.useragent + ' Hughes-PFB/' +
          params.agentid + '/' + params.tracetags
        headers['User-Agent'] = userAgent
        headers['Connection'] = 'Close'
      }
      
      proxy = 'http://' + ConfigHandler.getConfig().iosPrefetchProxyIp +
        ':' + ConfigHandler.getConfig().iosPrefetchProxyPort
      options['proxy'] = proxy
    }

    this.httpClient = request.get(options, (err, response, body) => {
      let result = {}
      if (!err) {
        this.response = response
        this.bodyLen = body.length
        logger.debug('%s Response info, %s', this.tag, this.resourceInfo())
        result = {
          statuscode: response.statusCode,
          headers: response.headers,
          body: body
        }
      } else {
        logger.error('%s, fetchUrl() failed! cause=%s, url=%s', JSON.stringify(this), err.message,
          this.url)
      }
      
      if (this.httpClient) {
           logger.debug('%s, fetchUrl() ending connection!', JSON.stringify(this.httpClient))
          this.httpClient.abort()
        }
        if (response && response.socket)         {
          response.socket.destroy()
        } 
      callBack(result, err)
    })
  }

  cancelFetch () {
    if (this.httpClient) {
      logger.debug('%s, Cancelling fetch for url=%s', this.tag, this.url)
      this.httpClient.abort()
      this.httpClient = null
      this.url = null
    }
  this.response.socket.removeAllListeners()
    }
  }

  close () {
    if (this.response && this.response.socket) {

      this.response.socket.destroy()
      //logger.debug('%s, close(), after socket.destroy(), statusTCP=%s', JSON.stringify(this.response), this.response.socket)
    }
    if (this.httpClient) {
      logger.debug('%s, Closing HTTP connection for url=%s', this.tag, this.url)
      this.httpClient.abort()
      this.httpClient = null
      this.url = null
      this.response = null
    }
  }
```

Comment: share you code to better understand the problem

Comment: I just added it, sorry.

Comment: which module you are using for `request`

Comment: Im using 'request.js'